# Where are Chrome "Default " Themes stored?

Tags: google-chrome, themes

So I have viewed some old threads of this particular question recently, however it does not seem to solve the current problem I am looking for.

What I am looking for is the location for the "default" chrome themes.

I.e: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/chrome_themes

In %appdata%/Local/Google/Chrome/Extensions one is able to search something such as   "theme_ntp" in this folder and it will show the results of the background image for downloaded themes (Not the "default" theme).

It appears default themes are not stored here, anybody have a clue where it is?
I should mention, **my goal is to change the background to a custom image (something.png) over the theme, which doesn't work when you have a theme installed.**

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/310486/where-are-the-chrome-theme-files-saved) is in:

`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`

I had checked myself (I use Google Chrome) and I confirm this information as being accurate.

Comment: Yes, this is where themes not made by Google are stored. If you download someone else's theme it is stored here. However, when you download one of the themes in the link in the original question^, it does not get stored there for some reason. Perhaps it is built into Chrome by default?